# LeetCode не совпадает ответ

Tags: java, алгоритм

В общем, суть проблемы такова, пытаюсь решить задачу на leetcode, вроде бы решил, отправил. Говорит. что вывод не соответсвует тому, что он ожидает. Запускаю свой код с теми же входными данными у себя локально, и вывод уже такой, какой должен быть и там.

Текст [задачи](https://leetcode.com/problems/all-paths-from-source-to-target/)

> Given a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of n nodes labeled from 0 to n - 1, find all possible paths from node 0 to node n - 1, and return them in any order.
> The graph is given as follows: graph[i] is a list of all nodes you can visit from node i (i.e., there is a directed edge from node i to node graph[i][j]).

```
static List<List<Integer>> answer = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> currentPath = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] graph = new int[][] {
            {4, 3, 1},
            {3, 2, 4},
            {3},
            {4},
            {}
    };
    Solution797 solution797 = new Solution797();
    var result = solution797.allPathsSourceTarget(graph);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public List<List<Integer>> allPathsSourceTarget(int[][] graph) {
    getPaths(0, graph);
    return answer;
}

public void getPaths(int currPos, int[][] graph) {
    if (currentPath == null) {
        currentPath = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    currentPath.add(currPos);

    if (graph[currPos].length == 0) {
        answer.add(new ArrayList<>(currentPath));
        currentPath.remove((Integer) currPos);

        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < graph[currPos].length; i++) {
        getPaths(graph[currPos][i], graph);

        currentPath.remove((Integer) graph[currPos][i]);
    }
}
```

На литкоде
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что то в вашем коде явно работает не так, как надо.
Я бы убрал все поля, как статические и не статические, так как ваш экземпляр класса может быть запущен на нескольких тестах, а вы в него состояние добавили.

Особенно вопросы возникают к статическим полям. Вот оно там зачем?

Вот этот мой код прошел все проверки без проблем

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> allPathsSourceTarget(int[][] graph) {
        LinkedList<Integer> path = new LinkedList<>();
        path.add(0);
        List<List<Integer>> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        getAllPaths(graph, path, graph.length - 1, ret);
        return ret;
    }

    private void getAllPaths(int[][] graph, LinkedList<Integer> path, int target, List<List<Integer>> paths) {

        int latest = path.getLast();
        if (latest == target) {
            List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>(path);
            paths.add(ret);
            return;
        }

        for (int n : graph[latest]) {
            path.add(n);
            getAllPaths(graph, path, target, paths);
            path.removeLast();
        }
    }
}
```

Как видите, нет состояния в классе - нет и проблем с состоянием.

Comment: Спасбио большое! Не приходилось до этого использовать рекурсию, поэтому идея хранить состояние в поле класса показалась заманчивой.